# UIViewController not being released when popped

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have a table view that when a cell is selected it pushes a view controller onto the navigation stack:

```
SAPostTableViewController *postViewController = [[SAPostTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([SAPostTableViewController class]) bundle:nil];
postViewController.site = site;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postViewController animated:YES];
[postViewController release];
```

SAPostTableViewController has a static tableView which, and it's cells, are loaded from a nib.

I have overridden the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method:

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        self.sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}
```

`sections` is a retained property.

In `viewDidLoad` of `SAPostTableViewController` I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cellVisibiltyChanged:) name:@"SAStaticCellVisibiltyChanged" object:nil];
}
```

and so to match in `viewDidUnload`:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"SAStaticCellVisibiltyChanged" object:nil];
}
```

However when I press the back button in the navigation bar (all standard behaviour, no override) and `SAPostTableViewController` is popped, it doesn't call `viewDidUnload` or `dealloc`. So this means that if I then reselect the cell that pushes `SAPostTableViewController` it creates a new instance of `SAPostTableViewController` and repeating this back and forward just means the memory usage keeps increasing as the popped `SAPostTableViewController`s never get deallocated. (I know this by running Instruments on allocations)

The weird thing is that if I release SAPostTableViewController twice then it works as I'd expect:

```
SAPostTableViewController *postViewController = [[SAPostTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([SAPostTableViewController class]) bundle:nil];
postViewController.site = site;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postViewController animated:YES];
[postViewController release];
[postViewController release];
```

(If I add a third release statement, it crashes as I'd expect it to with just 2)

I have resorted to using `retainCount` and stepped through the lines of code the are executed in the first line of the directly above code, the retainCount remains at 1. It jumps up between the first and second line, so I can't see anywhere it is being retain an extra time?

The SAPostTableViewController is only used in this place, it is not a delegate of anything, nor does it have a delegate.

How can I find a fix, or is it something simple I've missed?

Here is what Instruments shows after pushing SAPostTableViewController just once (with only one release statement):
[image]

And what it shows after navigating back and forth repeatedly (again, one release statement):
[image]

Comment: whaty happens here : cellVisibiltyChanged

Comment: According to Instruments, who else is retaining the `SAPostTableViewController`?

Comment: Nothing it seems, I've put a screenshot of what instruments shows when I have just the one release statement. And then what it shows if I go back and forward multiple times. Thanks :)

Comment: Two things I can't fully understand: what

Comment: Two things I can't fully understand: what's the NSStringFromClass() good for instead of just a string with the xib-name, and then the `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` - did you mean `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`?

Comment: By using NSStringFromClass, if I rename the class using refactoring, then it will change that for me, if I use a string then I have to remember to do it manually. And as sections is a retained property, I want an autoreleased dictionary, and using [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] is a short way for [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease].

Comment: @Jonathan. that's actually unnecessary. The [docs for `UIViewController.nibName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW13) say that if you specify `nil` as the nib name, it'll try to derive the name from the name of the class (assuming you haven't overridden `-loadView`).

Comment: @DaveDeLong, I had tried that, but some reason it wouldn't find the nib. I tried again now and it seems to be working again. I probably made a spelling mistake in the nib's filename the first time, as I've had to remake the nib since then and my spelling is not great :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Object when you clic one Cell, why you don't create your Object (`SAPostTableViewController`) in the init Method and then Push the same object watch time you click in Cell

you can do something like this :

```
postViewController = [[SAPostTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([SAPostTableViewController class]) bundle:nil];
```

and in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
postViewController.site = site; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postViewController animated:YES]; [postViewController release]; 

    }
```

Comment: Because it has completely different content each time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem is, but here are some things to consider:

1. You should absolutely **NOT** release the view controller twice.  If you have indeed discovered a memory leak in UIKit (which is unlikely), then it is likely it would be fixed in a future version of UIKit.  That means that anyone running an old version of your app on a new version of the operating system would experience nothing but crashes (due to over-releasing the view controller).  It is better to leak than to crash.  A leaky app is still a usable app (at least until you leak too much).  But a crashing app can't be run at all.
2. `-viewDidUnload` is not doing what you think it should be doing.  It is only called when the view controller's view is unloaded *due to memory pressure*.  It is not called during normal deallocation.  It would be wiser to rely on `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewDidDisappear:` instead.

Comment: So instead of adding the notification observer in viewDidLoad, I should do it in viewWillAppear? When you add an observer for notifications in viewDidLoad, where should you remove the observer?

Comment: I finally found the problem, I was using `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` (separate to the code I posted) and I had used `self` in the block so it couldn't get released.

Comment: @Jonathan. the most reliable place would be `-dealloc`, but that will only work if you haven't introduced a retain cycle.